# Debugging (Stepping through) a VS setup project, How do you do it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, custom-action

Im trying to debug a setup project that I created in c# (VS)...  I have the project currently set to a "Debug" and NOT "Release" and I have added the following code to my custom actions area...

```
public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached == false) Debugger.Launch();
    MessageBox.Show("Installing Application...");

    //Continue with install process
    base.Install(stateSaver);
}

//Code to perform at the time of uninstalling application 
public override void Uninstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached == false) Debugger.Launch();
    MessageBox.Show("Uninstalling Application...");

    //Continue with uninstall process
    base.Uninstall(savedState);
}
```

When I go to install (Right click on setup project-> install) it works as expected and I can use F11 to step through each line.  When I go to uninstall (Right click on setup project-> uninstall) it will not let me step through using F11 or continue using F5 or see any of the intellisense popups (like variable values, etc).  Though I can click the file menu option to do each (Debug->Continue and Debug->Step Into).

Any ideas why that's the case and how I might be able to get that functionality?

**Additional Question:** Is it possible to change any code (like adding a message box) while stepping through the setup project during runtime like you would with a normal program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
In my case I was trying to debug my custom install actions Install() and Uninstall().  I ended up adding the following to my custom actions...

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached == false) Debugger.Launch();
```

That was simple enough, below is an example of it in place...

```
//Code to perform at the time of installing application
public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached == false) Debugger.Launch();

    CustomParameters cParams = new CustomParameters();
    cParams.Add("InstallPath", this.Context.Parameters["targetdir"]);
    cParams.SaveState(stateSaver);

    //Continue with install process
    base.Install(stateSaver);
}
```